# What are these dark green spots inside raw eggs?

Tags: eggs, mold

I bought a tray of eggs recently. They aren't old, I have them in the fridge, and the date stamped on the egg says they are good for another month.

In two eggs that I cracked open today, there were dark green spots inside the shell (looked like mold maybe?), and floating around the egg white.

Any idea what that is? Is it a sign that the whole tray may be contaminated with something??

I only noticed the green on the shell after I mixed one of the eggs into a bread dough, and now I need to know if I should throw the dough out or not (it's a huge batch of dough).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [The Egg Safety Center site](http://www.eggsafety.org/consumers/consumer-faqs), black or green spots inside the egg are the result of bacterial or fungal contamination of the egg.

The use by date is only an estimate, so if your eggs are moldy, I'd dispose them.

Comment: sounds like mold... but i wonder if it will make me sick to eat bread baked with it. it was just one egg with about 5lbs of flour. it's a real waste to throw that all out...

Comment: Some molds are harmless. Some can make you really sick. Some molds can kill you. Is it worth the risk of 5lbs of flour to find out if you'll still be around next year?

Comment: no, of course not. but perhaps someone would know if egg mold is the harmless type or not?

Comment: maybe they didn't live to contribute to this site again.  (bad joke - sorry!) But seriously, @estherh - barring any new insight to egg mold, I hope we hear that you threw away the dough and started again with fresh eggs! :-)

Answer (score 4):

This is why I usually crack eggs into 2 bowls so one bad one won't contaminate whatever I'm making. I didn't do that tonight and had to throw out a batch of cornbread. I always go by the rule "When in doubt, throw it out!"

There was no obvious crack in the egg. When I opened it I noticed a brown discoloration in the yolk. Then I looked in the shell and saw mold or bacteria colonies or whatever. Never have seen anything like that before. Have found a few rotten ones but I've been cooking a long time. Anyway, just very curious and wondering if I should report it to someone or not.

Comment: I think you mean "When in doubt, throw it out!"

Answer (score -1):

I just found green mold in the shell of the egg shell and a large black dot on the yolk; the date says good until Sept 1.  I throughout the rest of the eggs, kept the one in question and contacted the egg farm to report it.  Not worth getting sick over a dollar or two, or worse dying.

I'd definitely go with the when in doubt throw it out.  Fs